Prove existence of a special node that is connected with all the nodes of set S.

In a simple undirected graph of $99$ nodes where the degree of each
node belongs to $[81, 90]$, prove that there exists a subset $S$ of
nodes of size $10$ and a special node $v \notin S$ such that all nodes
in $S$ have equal degree and are connected to $v$.

The part to prove that there exists a set of at least $10$ nodes with all having the same degree can be easily proved using the pigeon-hole principle. But I'm finding the proof of the existence of $v$ to be a little tricky. We can make some more observations, but I am not able to prove the second part. Any ideas?

I'm sure that this question was asked before on this stack exchange, but I can't seem to find it right now
